# Compiling ntfs-3g from source doesn't yield ntfs-3g binary

Tags: mount, ntfs-3g

I've been battling ntfs-3g for a day now. My goal is to be able to add a non-auto entry to fstab such that I can type `mount /media/kael/my-ntfs-partition` and have it mount `rw` without any weird messages or errors and without having to use `sudo`.

I've now **uninstalled ntfs-3g** via `sudo apt-get remove ntfs-3g` (which only removed the ntfs-3g package and apparently nothing else, i.e., no dependencies), and have **compiled ntfs-3g from the source** provided [here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/). However, strangely, when I compiled, I got a bunch of binaries, like `ntfs-3g.probe`, `ntfs-3g.secaudit`, `ntfs-3g.usermap`, `ntfscat`, `ntfscluster`, `ntfscmp`, `ntfsfix`, `ntfsinfo`, and `ntfsls`, but **I did NOT get an `ntfs-3g` binary**.

To clarify, now when I type `which ntfs-3g`, I get nothing. Furthermore, when I mount my partition, I no longer get errors, but it also mounts read-only, indicating that the system is not using ntfs-3g (presumably because, for some reason, it wasn't created from my compile).

Any ideas??

Thanks,
Kael

Comment: Why did you uninstall the `ntfs-3g` package? What was wrong with it?

Comment: Using a local installation vs a binary package from your distribution is rarely if ever a good way to go. Backups and local customizations of distribution binary packages are also always an option.

Comment: FaheemMitha: I compiled from scratch as a response to the error I received when trying to mount my partition without root privileges: "Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root." I already tried setuid on the package binary and it didn't work, so the only option left was to recompile --with-fuse=internal

wurtel: I uninstalled the ntfs-3g package because I didn't want to worry about conflicting binaries and related files.